# Multiple Jobs in Quartz Scheduler not running according to the triggers

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, jobs, stateful

I have configured a quartz scheduler with 4 different jobs, each triggering every 1 minute. The schedule I have configured is as follows:-

```html
 <schedule>

  <job>
   <name>LockMonitor</name>
   <job-class>background.jobs.LockMonitor</job-class>
  </job>
  <trigger>
   <simple>
    <name>LockJobTrigger</name>
    <job-name>LockMonitor</job-name>
    <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
    <repeat-interval>60000</repeat-interval>  
   </simple>
  </trigger>

  <job>
   <name>LogMonitor</name>
   <job-class>background.jobs.LogMonitorJob</job-class>
  </job>
  <trigger>
   <simple>
    <name>LogMonitorTrigger</name>
    <job-name>LogMonitor</job-name>
    <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
    <repeat-interval>60000</repeat-interval>
   </simple>
  </trigger>

  <job>
   <name>ProcessMonitor</name>
   <job-class>background.jobs.ProcessMonitor</job-class>
  </job>
  <trigger>
   <simple>
    <name>ProcessMonitorTrigger</name>
    <job-name>ProcessMonitor</job-name>
    <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count> 
    <repeat-interval>60000</repeat-interval>
   </simple>
  </trigger>

  <job>
   <name>HealthCheck</name>
   <job-class>background.jobs.HealthCheck</job-class>
  </job>
  <trigger>
   <simple>
    <name>HealthCheckTrigger</name>
    <job-name>HealthCheck</job-name>
    <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count> 
    <repeat-interval>60000</repeat-interval>
   </simple>
  </trigger>

 </schedule>
```

The problem that I am encountering is that only the 1st and 2nd jobs are getting executed most of the time. The 3rd and 4th jobs - namely ProcessMonitor and HealthCheck are getting executed only once in a while. Can someone help me with this? Is this because I have configured the same time interval for all the jobs? Is there any means by which I can ensure that all the 4 jobs are executed before starting the next set of execution?

I have configured all the jobs as implements StatefulJob

Answer (score 0):

How many threads did you configure? When I keep the number of thread == number of jobs registered to run in the Quartz framework, everything seems to run as expected.